# ImportError: No module named labjack

Tags: python

I am getting the following error while using python with T7 labjacks.

```
from labjack import ljm

# Open first found LabJack
handle = ljm.openS("ANY", "ANY", "ANY")

# Call eReadName to read the serial number from the LabJack.
name = "SERIAL_NUMBER"
result = ljm.eReadName(handle, name)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testLJ.py", line 1, in <module>
    from labjack import ljm
ImportError: No module named labjack
```

Comment: "No module named labjack" means Python can't find it.  Which usually means it's not installed, or hasn't been correctly installed.  How did you install it?

Comment: One common newbie problem is if you have a file `labjack.py` in the current directory, it will shadow the system file.

Answer (score 0):

As documented on [Labjack - Python for LJM - Windows, Mac, Linux](https://labjack.com/support/software/examples/ljm/python):

> **Instructions**
>
> Install the LJM Python modules with pip, which is
>   commonly installed with Python, using the following command:
>
> ```
>  python -m pip install labjack-ljm
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
>  pip install labjack-ljm
> ```
>
> **Troubleshooting**
>
> If you get the following error:
>
> ```
> ImportError: No module named labjack
> ```
>
> Make  sure you install for the Python version you will be using. For
>   example, on Linux if both Python 2.7 and 3.5 are installed, you can
>   install to Python 3.5 with:
>
> ```
> $ python3.5 -m pip labjack-ljm install
> ```